# HTTP POST request progress on server side

Tags: c#, http, servicestack

I'm developing a mobile app to upload pictures to a server. On server side i have C# and ServiceStack. I'd like to know if there is a way to capture the progress of the upload process (via HTTP POST multipart/form-data) and do sth every time a chunk of the request arrives (notify about the progress another client via Web Socket).

I know from the uploading client side it is easy to get to know how much of the data was already sent but i'd like to also know it on the server side. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to provide progress updates on the server for file uploads as ASP.NET HttpHandlers like ServiceStack are only invoked after the files are received by the server.

I'd stick to client callbacks to report upload server progress, e.g:

```
client.OnUploadProgress = (bytesWritten, total) => 
    "Written {0}/{1} bytes...".Print(bytesWritten, total);

client.PostFileWithRequest<UploadResponse>(url, new FileInfo(path), 
    new Upload { CreatedBy = "Me" });
```